# Is it possible for the thymeleaf template and jsp pages to coexist in a Spring application?

Tags: spring-boot, jsp, thymeleaf

I created a project called SpringJsp in STS 4 (Spring Boot version 3.2.2) in which I inserted the following dependency in the pom.xml file:

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I then created the following folders:

```
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/
```

In the application.properties I have inserted these settings:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

In the jsp folder I created the file testprova.jsp
Then I created the MainController controller that points to the jsp page:

```
package it.springtestjsp;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("")
public class MainController {

    @GetMapping("/testprova")
    public String test() {
        return "testprova";
    }
}
```

In this way the testprova.jsp page runs correctly.
However, if I install the thymeleaf dependency

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

gives me the following error:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
```

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
```

```
Fri Feb 02 18:18:41 CET 2024
```

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
```

```
Log: 024-02-02T18:18:41.818+01:00[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m17936[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [testprova], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers] with root cause
```

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [testprova], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  Look at the documentation for configuring multiple view resolvers.  You won't be able to do this with a property-driver approach, though.

Comment: Hi lane.maxwell,
Can you write the third parts documentation url ?

Thank you
Andrew